# Dimension free Concentration bounds for Martingales

Tags: probability, martingales, random-walk, correlation

Consider the following random process which is defined on $n$ numbers $0\leq x_1,\ldots,x_n\leq 1$:

*At each step, pick an arbitrary number, say $x_i$. Then randomly (and independently) change its value to $x'_i$ such that $0\leq x'_i \leq 1$ and $E[x'_i]=x_i$. We stop the process when all the numbers are either $0$ or $1$.*

Given that the process is stopped, it is easy to verify that Chernoff bounds hold in the following sense: Let the outcome of the process be the binary numbers $y_1,\ldots,y_n$. For any subset $S$ of indices define $\mu_S=\sum_{i\in S} x_i$, then we have
\begin{align*}
\Pr\left\{\biggm|\mu_S - \sum_{i\in S} y_i\biggm| >\epsilon \cdot \mu_S \right\} \leq 2e^{-\epsilon^2 \mu_S /3}.
\end{align*}

I need to find a similar bound for a slightly more complicated process:

*At each step, pick a subset of numbers of size at most $d$, say $\{x_{i_1},\ldots,x_{i_d}\}$, and change their values to $\{x'_{i_1},\ldots,x'_{i_d}\}$ by either increasing all of these numbers or decreasing all of them. This is done in such a way that $0\leq x'_{i_j}\leq 1$ and $E[x'_{i_j}]=x_{i_j}$* for all $j$.

Can we get a similar result for this process too? For instance, is it possible to replace the right-hand side of the above bound with $2e^{-\epsilon^2 \mu/O(d)}$? Thank you very much.

Comment: Note: I have tried Azuma's inequality but unfortunately I could not get a bound which is only dependent to $\mu_S$ (and not $|S|$).

Comment: Do you pick the arbitrary $x_i$ uniformly at random? Do you pick a subset $\{x_{i_1},\ldots\}$ uniformly at random also?

Comment: No, none of them are picked uniformly at random. The chosen subset is dependent on the outcome of the previous (increase/decrease) operations. For instance, we can have the following scenario: if the first operation turned out to be increasing the values, the second operation happens on subset A, otherwise, it happens on subset B.  So the whole process can be defined by a "decision tree".

Comment: You may find the following papers relevant. http://chekuri.cs.illinois.edu/papers/intersection-rounding-soda.pdf and https://arxiv.org/abs/0909.4348